# Adding multiple repeating rows in apache POI 3.15 excel

Tags: excel, apache-poi

I can add one repeating row or consecutive repeating rows using function setRepeatingRows. I am wondering if it's possible to have multiple repeating rows as follows:

- Row 5 repeats from row 5 to row 500
- Row 503 repeats for the rest of the data

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First question: Where are the rows repeating? In `apache poi`?  No but in `Excel`'s print view and/or while printing from `Excel`. So can `Excel` set this requirement? No it can't, see [Repeat specific rows or columns on every printed page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Repeat-specific-rows-or-columns-on-every-printed-page-0d6dac43-7ee7-4f34-8b08-ffcc8b022409). So can `apache poi` do something what `Excel`cannot do? No, how should it can?

Comment: If you can do it in Excel, then there is likely a way to get it in Apache POI as well, at least via some low-level APIs. So you should first make sure it is possible in Excel itself.

Comment: @AxelRichter Yes, in excel print view.